How to only hard code allowable values once for both type checking (TypeAlias) and runtime checking (x in Allowed)
Suppose I have a function that only allows 2 inputs, so for static type checking only I'd do:
Letter: TypeAlias = Literal["a", "b"]

def my_func(letter: Letter)->str:
    ...

but I still want my function to validate the value at run time with something like:
if letter not in ["a", "b"]:
    raise ValueError("must enter a or b")

Now I have two places where ["a", "b"] have to be hard coded which I'd like to avoid.
A few things I tried are:
"a" in Letter
# returns False

Letter: TypeAlias = Literal(VALID_LETTERS:=["a", "b"])
# raises Literal can't be instantiate.


VALID_LETTERS=["a", "b"]
Letter: TypeAlias = Literal[VALID_LETTERS]
# Variable not allowed in type expression

I also considered using an Enum as that would tick the box of keeping the allowed values for the purposes of type checking and run time checking in the same place but it forces users of the function have to import the Enum class too which I don't want. It also doesn't give the input hint pop-up so it's not good for me in this case.
Is there a way to have my allowable values only hard coded once for both type checking and run time checking?
